# List append() not appending user input

Tags: python, authentication

I have a program and I'm trying to get user input and add it to an array

```py
ids = ['rex', 'test']
pwds = ['rex', 'test']

def user():
    adding_username = raw_input('username: ')
    adding_password = raw_input('password: ')
    ids.append(adding_username)
    pwds.append(adding_password)
    print('\nadded: {}:{}'.format(adding_username, adding_password))
user()
```

I want it to add the inputs to the list but not working sadly

Comment: That definitely will add to the lists. What do you mean by "but not working sadly"? How are you checking the lists? Your `print` is only printing the input, not the lists.

Comment: im re-opening the file, thats how im checking

Comment: And how are you writing to the file? Show a [mcve].

Comment: i thought append will add the string to the list and would write it on it own, how do you recommend i do this?

Comment: @babyyrex just do this: `print(ids)`. It will print the username you added, as well as 'rex' and 'test'.

Comment: No. Adding to a list does not mean that that list is saved between runs of the program. `ids` only exists as long as you have the program open. You'll need to save the list to file manually and read it from the disk later when you want to use it. [This](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) may be a good intro.

Answer (score 2):

Adding items to a list wont add the actual item string inside your program 
 source file
you can open a new file and write the list to it if you want

for example:

```
ids = ['rex', 'test']
pwds = ['rex', 'test']

def user():
    adding_username = raw_input('username: ')
    adding_password = raw_input('password: ')
    ids.append(adding_username)
    pwds.append(adding_password)

    # print the ids list
    print(ids)

    # print the pwds list
    print(pwds)

    # write the lists to a file "myfile.txt"
    with open("myfile.txt", "w") as myfile:
        # use the 'str' function on an object to turn it to string
        # or in other words turn it to "text"
        myfile.write(str(ids))
        myfile.write("\n") # start new line in file
        myfile.write(str(pwds))

    print('\nadded: {}:{}'.format(adding_username, adding_password))

user()
```

now if you open the file named "myfile.txt" in the same directory you will find the lists inside of it